# Do solid insoluble ions react with soluble ions in aqueous solution?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, ions

Do solid and insoluble ions (like aluminium phosphate) react with soluble ions in aqueous solution (like potassium sulfate)?  When would a solid ion react with an ion in aqueous solution in general?

Comment: Surface equilibria happen all the time, but what are you imagining with this example?

Comment: And @Maurice here should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_energy

Comment: @ Mithoron. The mentioned publication does not explain the difference between the solubilities of $\ce{CaF_2}$ and $\ce{CaCl2}$

Comment: @Mithoron, I thought AlPO4 (insoluble) and K2SO4 (water-soluble) were a good example for this question. I was wondering whether they would swap ions in a precipitation reaction.  In purely basic information about double displacement reactions I've found online, both reactants are always initially in aqueous solution, never in solid or gas phase. I can't find anything about the process solid ionic substances undergo if they are placed in a solution.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be asking about is a two phase system, a solid phase in equilibrium with ions in solution. For such a system there are two reactions occurring at the same rate. Thus some of the solid is constantly dissolving and some of the ions from solution depositing at the same rate.

There is a named process, [Oswald ripening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostwald_ripening), that describes the interaction in such a solution. The overall effect is that smaller particles are more likely to dissolve so the particle size tends to grow as the process continues since larger particles have a smaller surface area to volume ratio.

Comment: Thanks. I think this points me to what I am trying to understand.